# How to exclude some of the "unable to open include file *.h" errors in pclint

Tags: c, include, header-files, lint, pc-lint

I am using PC lint in my project. My project is compatible to build in both windows and linux. So i have used windows header(visualstudio) files and linux header files(gcc) in my project. I am running pclint entirely for all the file. Its giving error message

```
Unable to open include file *.h
```

I dont want to suppress this error in std.lnt file and i dont want to add

```
-elint errorcode
```

before the include statement. Please suggest me is there any way to suppress particualar headerfiles in std.lnt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you don't really get message

```
Unable to open include file *.h
```

but are really getting message

```
Unable to open include file fred.h
```

for some file fred.h.

If I am correct, then add these two lines to std.lnt:

```
-efile(322,fred.h)
-efile(7,fred.h)
```

Answer (score 1):

Protect the relevant includes with platform-dependant preprocessor symbols:

```
#if defined PLATFORM_PC
#include <whatever/is/needed.h>
#else if defined PLATFORM_POSIX
#include <stdio.h>
#endif
```

Then make sure you define `PLATFORM_PC` when checking the code with PC-Lint, so that it never sees the includes for the platform it doesn't understand.